# Strange exceptions using FindControl after implementing master pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have some simple repeater code given here:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultsRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="ResultsDS">
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <table id="Results" class="data">
  <tr id="Header" runat="server">
   <th>Item</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I used to be able to then access the repeater to get said header, as such:

```
HtmlTableRow header = ResultsRepeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("Header") as HtmlTableRow;
```

After implementing master pages, I noticed my calls to header.InnerText and .InnerHtml throw exceptions, specifically:

```
'header.InnerHtml' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
'header.InnerText' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

Can anyone share what's going on with me? I am of course assuming master pages caused this, since it's the only thing I've changed besides minor updates (that should not affect this in any way).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the HtmlTableRow.InnerHtml property says this: "Do not read from or assign a value to this property. Otherwise, a System.NotSupportedException exception is thrown. This property is inherited from the HtmlContainerControl class and is not applicable to the HtmlTableRow class."

Looks like you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem with Master Pages. HtmlTableRow's InnerHtml and InnerText properties are designed like that , they will throw NotSupportedException. Following is the implementation of InnerText property as defined in HtmlTableRow class :-

```
public override string InnerText
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(SR.GetString("InnerText_not_supported", new object[] { base.GetType().Name }));
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(SR.GetString("InnerText_not_supported", new object[] { base.GetType().Name }));
    }
}
```

And its the same for InnerHtml property.You might have to rethink on your current approach.